# Dependent Drop Downs on Different sheets in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to have a drop down list in Sheet A that derives its data from Sheet B. And then, a dependent drop down list a few cells away on Sheet A that only shows a custom list depending on the first drop down list based on values also in Sheet B. I've tried doing =indirect and following dependent drop down tutorials online but keep getting an error. I can't have a header in sheet A, but can possibly put the dropdown name to the left of the drop down.

See below for pics.
Thank you!

Sheet A:
[image: Sheet A]
Sheet B:
[image: Sheet B]

Comment: Did you search SO for "Dependent Drop Downs" - there are a lot of solutions ...

Comment: Yes I searched but nothing for my specific needs

Comment: this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGIb6mVvEMY) is very informative, it is explained for Google Spreadsheet, but the logic is the same using `FILTER` function for excel. Here you have a [play list](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIJbcBBH88M&list=PLmHVyfmcRKywYhC1Q9eZqR7D-_cdiwl6y) about the same topic (this is only for excel), I am sure your case will be there, if not please update your question so it can be easier to understand. why your problem is unique or different. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All, thanks for the help. I used the =filter forumula to create another table on the 2nd sheet and had the data validation just reference that